# Why is the Blip so brutal but the Snap is soft?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

We've seen in *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* two Snaps to be performed, the first by Thanos, the second by

> Tony Stark AKA Iron Man.

Each of them were really soft, happening with a delay by becoming dust.

But in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, in the first minutes of the movie, we can see

> the Blip happened, which is the reverse Snap of Hulk.

It's so sudden, no warning, no animation. Just a pop of people.

If the reverse Snap has been performed by Hulk, and in the stress of making good things, he didn't think about make it smooth.

Why has the second Snap (Tony's) been made like the first one? Was it to mimic Thanos to have the last word? Or is it just the way the Stones perform the Snap?

Comment: “It's so sudden, no warning, no animation. Just a pop of people” — I've only seen *Far From Home* once, but I seem to remember a short reverse-dust animation for the snapped students returning. It's possible the Infinity Stones have a sense of humour, and were keen for at least one returning person to immediately get hit in the head by a basketball.

Comment: Well, one is disappearing and the other is appearing. I honestly think they appear much faster because it is humorous

Comment: When making people reappear it makes sense they will appear in one go, the Hulk is clever enough to make sure people reappear safely (e.g if they where in a plane they are now on the ground) so I imagine he also realises the trauma of watching your body reappear slowly is probably not something people want. Alternatively when making people vanish they may need to be broken down slowly. Reappearing them the stones may do all the processing in the background and then just make them appear.

Comment: Maybe Thanos chose to send people to dust slowly so that others could actual observe what happened.

Answer (score 16):

I've been searching for this on and off since it was asked and after looking at the scene again I think the answer is actually quite simple. In *Spider-Man: Far From Home* we only see two comparative clips of the Snap versus the Blip, both of the sports hall in Midtown School of Science and Technology. If you watch [the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQUYO4swfEw) all of the people in the sports hall are snapped away at pretty much the same time. The delay between each person isn't as extreme as we in *Avengers: Infinity War*. Gif starts at ~1:30 in the linked video:

[image: Gif from a video taken from a camera phone of someone in the stands watching the band in the sports hall, all of a sudden band members start to get dusted and people in the stands do to; the camera jerks around at different dusted people]

Then when we see the Blip happen, we get a brief animation of the people being "rebuilt" from the dust, notice the white highlight on them. They also have some delay on coming back, not all are shown appearing at the same time. Gif starts at ~1:37 in the linked video:

[image: Gif from a video taken from a camera phone of someone in the stands watching a basketball match in the sports hall, all of a sudden band members start to appear in the middle of the court and people in the stands do to; the camera jerks around at different people reappearing]

From this we can determine that there actually doesn't appear to be a difference between how hard/soft the Snap and the Blip actually are. It's just that from the scene we see in *Spider-Man: Far From Home* everyone was Snapped/Blipped at pretty much the same time. It also appears to take longer to Snap because the dust from the person hangs around in the air, whereas in the Blip it immediately creates the person.

Note that in *WandaVision* we see Monica come back in the Blip and it's clear it isn't always immediate but can be similar to from the Snap.

Comment: Also worth noting the Monica Rambeau's Blip seen on Wandavision is similar to the Snaps, but in reverse and seems to be as fast.

Comment: @alseether Nice call on some updated info!